# How to access IBM logDNA without going through ibm-console login

Tags: ibm-cloud, logdna

I'm trying to access IBM provided logDNA without logging in IBM console and traversing to LogDNA Dashboard location

I've no clue on how to proceed with this.

```
curl "https://logs.logdna.com/logs/ingest?hostname=EXAMPLE_HOST&mac=C0:FF:EE:C0:FF:EE&ip=10.0.1.101&now=$(date +%s)" \
-u INSERT_INGESTION_KEY: \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
-d \
'{
   "lines": [
     {
       "line":"This is an awesome log statement",
       "app":"myapp",
       "level": "INFO",
       "env": "production",
       "meta": {
         "customfield": {
           "nestedfield": "nestedvalue"
         }
       }
     }
   ]
}'
```

In the above code snippet the URL used is generic URL, instead of that I want to generate a URL for my IBM LogDNA which should be accessible through access token, so that I can use below type code snippet to push the logs to logDNA directly from the code.

Currently to open LogDNA dashboard, I login to IBM cloud UI and check in Observability section.
Is there a way we can access this through tokens and have a custom URL on which I can apply this?

Answer (score 2):

The steps to [obtain the dashboard URL using the command line](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/log-analysis?topic=log-analysis-get_loganalysis_web_url) are described in the related IBM Cloud Logging service documentation.
This works for the Activity Tracker the same way:

```
$ ibmcloud resource service-instance your-instance-name --output json | jq -r '.[0].dashboard_url'
```

Answer (score 0):

LogDNA documentation about REST ingestion is amazing...
But their service is really amazing. And this works for me:

In LogDNA dashboard, at [Settings -> Organization -> API Keys] you can find your key.

Let's say, you key is `77777haha77777777777hoho`.

In you curl command replace the second row with this:

```
-u "77777haha77777777777hoho:77777haha77777777777hoho" \
```

Entire tested command:

```
curl "https://logs.logdna.com/logs/ingest? 
hostname=EXAMPLE_HOST&mac=C0:FF:EE:C0:FF:EE&ip=10.0.1.101&now=1610830847530" \
-u "77777haha77777777777hoho:77777haha77777777777hoho" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
-d \
'{
  "lines":[
    {
        "timestamp":1610830847530,
        "line":"This is an awesome log statement",
        "file":"example.log"
    }
  ]
}'
```